# VSPackage theme-colored

Tags: xaml, vspackage, visual-studio-shell

I built a VSPackage for VS2015. How can I get the current theme colors to color my elements appropriate? I tried things like

```
 xmlns:vsfx="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0"
 Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.CommandBarOptionsBackgroundKey}}"
```

But that didn't work.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
xmlns:vs_shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0"
Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vs_shell:EnvironmentColors.CommandBarMenuBackgroundGradientBrushKey}}"
```

You can get the full list of colors here: [Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.EnvironmentColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.environmentcolors.aspx)